# wget command keeps returning error 500 but link works fine in a browser

Tags: wget

I'm trying to make a script to automatically download Sentinel satellite data. So I tried using the wget command provided in the user guide in their site but it doesn't work for some reason. It keeps returning 500 internal server error but when I try to access the download link on a browser, it works fine.

So, here is the link to the website instructions. https://scihub.copernicus.eu/twiki/do/view/SciHubUserGuide/5APIsAndBatchScripting#Download_via_Wget

And here is the download link, https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('e94ce3a1-a9c8-4162-a856-ce1d8c4c029a')/$value

Note: You need an account to download the data. And I have input my credentials on to the wget command but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 3):

Downloads from DHuS are most sensitive to proper escaping. With `wget` you need to at least escape the `$` sign (the command will actually work straight away for you if you have a `.netrc` file):

```
wget "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('e94ce3a1-a9c8-4162-a856-ce1d8c4c029a')/\$value"
```

The downside is that it saves output in a file named `$value`. I find that `curl` is a better command line client for working with ESA DataHub:

```
curl -JOn "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('e94ce3a1-a9c8-4162-a856-ce1d8c4c029a')/\$value"
```

Note the `-n` to use `.netrc`. You may omit it and authenticate with `-u` instead. This will use the proper remote name for the file, and produce local file `S1B_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20170607T100534_20170607T100559_005943_00A6CF_327E.zip`.

Answer (score 0):

The site possibly rejects the wget user agent, which would explain that you can download it with the browser but not with wget. You can fake a user agent in wget like this:

```
wget --header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0" ....
```